# Write a function that returns stream with lifetime

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am trying to implement "connect" that takes address and returns the TLS connection from `rustls`:

```
impl Connector {
  ...
  
  fn connect(&self, address: String) -> rustls::Stream<ClientConnection, TcpStream> {
    let target_address = address.parse().unwrap();
    let server_name = rustls::ServerName::from(address).unwrap();
    let mut tcp_stream = TcpStream::connect(target_address).unwrap();
    let mut client_conn = rustls::ClientConnection::new(Arc::new(self.client_config), server_name).unwrap();
    rustls::Stream::new(&mut client_conn, &mut tcp_stream)
  }
```

This does not work because `client_conn` and `tcp_stream` were borrowed within the function. And `Stream` has lifetime:

https://docs.rs/rustls/latest/rustls/struct.Stream.html

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Stream<'a, C: 'a + ?Sized, T: 'a + Read + Write + ?Sized> {
    /// Our TLS connection
    pub conn: &'a mut C,

    /// The underlying transport, like a socket
    pub sock: &'a mut T,
}
```

So, how do I create this `Stream` object within the `connect` function and returns accordingly with lifetime>

Comment: Please include the compiler error you get in your question. You're essentially trying to return a dangling reference: since `conn` and `sock` were constructed in the function scope, and were not moved out of the function, they will be `drop`ped (deallocated, closed). Why not store them directly in the struct instead of storing references?

Comment: @PitaJ because it's not his struct, it's a quote from a library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `Stream` is the wrong data type. It does not take ownership of the connection objects as far as I can see.

A quick search in the documentation makes me believe that what you are searching for is [`StreamOwned`](https://docs.rs/rustls/latest/rustls/struct.StreamOwned.html).