# Rust constructor with nested references

Tags: rust, lifetime, ownership

I'm quite new to Rust, I know just the basics, and coming from languages like C++ I'm currently struggling a bit with ownership and lifetimes.

I wanted to implement something like this:

```
struct A {}

struct B {}

struct C<'a> {
    field1: &'a mut A,
    field2: &'a mut B,
}

impl<'a> C<'a> {
    fn new(x: &'a mut A, y: &'a mut B) -> Self {
        Self { field1: x, field2: y }
    }
}

struct D<'a> {
    field1: A,
    field2: B,
    my_field: Option<C<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> D<'a> {
    fn new() -> D<'a> {
        let mut a = A {};
        let mut b = B {};

        let mut d = Self {
            field1: a,
            field2: b,
            my_field: None
        };
        
        d.my_field = Some(C::new(&mut d.field1, &mut d.field2));
        d
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let x = D::new();
}
```

This is a representation of my situation, in which I'm using a **library providing the implementation for A, B, and C**, and I want to wrap everything with a D struct. In particular, I'm interested in **creating an instance of C inside D, but C requires a reference to both A and B**.

If it helps, consider all these structs as network objects (socket, connection, stream, etc.).

The code refuses to compile because when leaving the D constructor I'm returning an object that is using references that are local to the constructor itself, but I couldn't figure out how to fix it.

Do you have any suggestions?

Note: I'm not really interested in storing A and B inside D, I did it just because I (wrongly) thought it could fix my issue, as I expected the ownership to be moved to D itself.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're used to C++ and being able to pass around pointers with no consequences, you're going to have a lot of friction in Rust as now you'll have to manage all kinds of lifetime issues as well. Can you wrap these in `Arc`? Do you really need references? If you have mutable references, you've already boxed yourself in, as those are limited to one and one only, so that may as well "own" the data inline.

Comment: Try to remove the self references, the borrow checker will not allow them.
I think you should provide a bit more context what you actually want to do. If its fine that D depends on a lifetime then just construct it with references to A and B

Comment: what you can do is: `impl D { fn get_C(&self) -> C }` and construct the `C` dynamically. This way the `C` has the lifetime bound to the lifetime of the `D` object

Comment: @jthulhu it doesn't, but it brought me very close to the solution I think as I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72003124/write-a-function-that-returns-stream-with-lifetime